# How do I access a JSON element in the DOM with watir-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, json, dom, watir-webdriver

I'm new to watir-webdriver, and am attempting to access a JSON element in the DOM from watir-webdriver. It's called `jsonText` in firebug, but I'm not sure how to access it and display it.

Here's what it contains in the DOM tab under Firebug:

```
jsonText    "{"packetType":"exec","id":1,"params":"","name":"test"}"
```

Here's what I tried so far:

```
puts fx.dom.window.jsonText
puts fx.div(:id=>"jsonText")
```

The first one errors out, the second one gives me this:

```
Watir::Div:0x00000003424d98
```

Comment: without a larger sample of the actual HTML around the thing you are looking for, it's hard to tell you how to locate it   Furthermore are you sure this is actually part of the DOM and not something within a script tag? if it's inside javascript, then how to access it becomes an entirely different animal

Answer (score 0):

Try it in IRB. In addition to having lots of fun, you can experiment a little. Here is [rdoc for div](http://jarib.github.com/watir-webdriver/doc/Watir/Div.html) so you can learn a little about what can be done with it. I recommend you do the following in IRB:

```
fx = Watir::Browser.new
fx.goto whateverUrlYouAreTesting
fx.div(:id=> "jsonText").<try your methods here>
```